# Want to match both uppercase and lowercase letters

Tags: javascript, regex

My Code:

I tried the following code

```
var str="I like green and want to build a GREENERY Earth with greening!"; 
var n=str.match(/green/g);
```

It is giving the result as

```
green,green
```

But I need the result as

```
green,GREEN,green
```

That is, I want to match both uppercase and lowercase letters. In this case, totally 3 green words are found.

Comment: try it

    var n=str.match(/green/ig);

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `i` flag, which will ignore the case-sensitiveness:

```
var n=str.match(/green/gi); 
//                      ^----here it is
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8ej59/)

Comment: Working fine as expected. Thanks.

Comment: How can we pass a variable instead of string? Is it even possible?